# Rotate Image - Java

Tags: algorithm

I am  doing a question where, given an n x n 2D matrix representing an image, rotate the image by 90 degrees (clockwise).You have to rotate the image in-place, which means you have to modify the input 2D matrix directly. DO NOT allocate another 2D matrix and do the rotation. This my my code:

```
   class Solution {
        public void rotate(int[][] matrix) {
            int size = matrix.length;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < matrix.length; i++){
                for(int y = 0 ; y < matrix[0].length ; y++){
                    matrix[i][y] = matrix[size - y - 1][i];
                    System.out.println(size - y - 1);
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the input and output results:

- input matrix: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`
- output matrix: `[[7,4,7],[8,5,4],[9,4,7]]`
- expected matrix: `[[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]]`

I do not really understand why I am getting duplicates in my output such as the number seven 3 times. On my `System.out.println` statement, I am getting the correct list of indexes :

```
2
0

1
0

0
0

2
1

1
1

0
1

2
2
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: When you do that `matrix[i][y] = matrix[size - y - 1][i];`, the *previous* value of `matrix[i][y]` is no longer available to be further rotated.

Comment: Do execute your code *by hand* on paper. (That takes one minute.) This will be instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I will try my best to explain it.

Let us consider an array of `size 4`.

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

*Now lets look at the numbers present only on the outside of the array:*

```
1  2  3  4
5        8
9        12
13 14 15 16
```

We will proceed by storing the *first element `1` in a `temporary variable`*. Next we will *`replace 1 by 13`, `13 by 16`, `16 by 4` and at last `4 by 1`* (whose value we already stored in the temporary variable).

*We will do the same for all the elements of the first row.*

Here is a pseudocode if you just want to rotate this outer ring, lets call it an `outer ring`:

```
for i = 0 to n-1
{
    temp = A[0][i];
    A[0][i] = A[n-1-i][0];
    A[n-1-i][0] = A[n-1-0][n-1-i];
    A[n-1-0][n-1-i] = A[i][n-1-0];
    A[i][n-1-0] = temp;
}
```

The code runs for a total of `n` times. *Once for each element of first row.* Implement this code an run it. You will see only the outer ring is rotated. Now lets look at the `inner ring`:

```
   6  7   
  10 11
```

*Now the loop in pseudocode only needs to run for `2` times and also our range of indexes has decreased.* For `outer ring`, the *loop started from `i = 0` and ended at `i = n-1`.* However, for the `inner ring` the *for loop need to run from `i = 1` to `i = n-2`*.

*If you had an array of size `n`, **to rotate the `xth` ring of the array**, the loop needs to run from `i = x` to `i = n-1-x`.*

Here is the code to rotate the entire array:

```
x = 0;
int temp;

while (x < n/2)
{
    for (int i = x;i < n-1-x;i++)
    {
        temp = arr[x][i];
        arr[x][i] = arr[n-1-i][x];
        arr[n-1-i][x] = arr[n-1-x][n-1-i];
        arr[n-1-x][n-1-i] = arr[i][n-1-x];
        arr[i][n-1-x] = temp;
    }

    x++;
}
```

*Here each value of x denotes the xth ring.*

> `0 <= x <= n-1`

The reason why the `outer loop` runs only for `x < n/2` times is *because each array has `n/2` rings when `n is even` and `n/2 + 1` rings if `n is odd`.*

I hope I have helped you. *Do comment if face any problems with the solution or its explanation.*